# PySide6: OAuth2 with Google

Tags: qt, oauth-2.0, pyside, pyside6

I tried to create an OAuth2 application similar to the one presented [here](https://www.qt.io/blog/2017/01/25/connecting-qt-application-google-services-using-oauth-2-0).
The part related to `modify_parameters` function I took from [here](https://appfluence.com/productivity/how-to-authenticate-qt-google-sso/).

The code:

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
from PySide6.QtNetworkAuth import QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow, QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler, QAbstractOAuth
from PySide6.QtGui import QDesktopServices
from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl, QByteArray

CLIENT_ID = 'your id'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'your secret'
AUTHORIZATION_URL = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth'
TOKEN_URL = 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token'
REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:3000'

def modify_parameters(stage, parameters):
    # Percent-decode the "code" parameter so Google can match it
    print(stage, parameters)
    if stage == QAbstractOAuth.Stage.RequestingAccessToken:
        code = parameters['code'][0]
        code = QUrl.fromPercentEncoding(code)
        code = QUrl.fromPercentEncoding(code.encode())
        parameters['code'] = [code]

        redirect_uri= parameters['redirect_uri'][0]  # Assuming parameters is a dict
        redirect_uri = QUrl.fromPercentEncoding(redirect_uri)
        #redirect_uri = QUrl.fromPercentEncoding(redirect_uri.encode())
        parameters['redirect_uri'] = [redirect_uri]


class OAuthApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # UI setup
        self.setWindowTitle('OAuth2 with PySide6 using QtNetworkAuth')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 200)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.connect_btn = QPushButton("Connect", self)
        self.connect_btn.clicked.connect(self.start_oauth)
        layout.addWidget(self.connect_btn)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        # OAuth2 setup
        self.oauth = QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow(self)
        self.oauth.setAuthorizationUrl(AUTHORIZATION_URL)
        self.oauth.setAccessTokenUrl(TOKEN_URL)
        self.oauth.setClientIdentifier(CLIENT_ID)
        self.oauth.setClientIdentifierSharedKey(CLIENT_SECRET)
        self.oauth.setScope("email")


        # Create a reply handler.
        self.reply_handler = QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler(3000, self.oauth)
        self.oauth.setReplyHandler(self.reply_handler)
        self.oauth.setModifyParametersFunction(modify_parameters)

        self.oauth.statusChanged.connect(self.auth_status_changed)
        self.oauth.authorizeWithBrowser.connect(QDesktopServices.openUrl)
        self.oauth.granted.connect(self.access_granted)
        self.reply_handler.tokensReceived.connect(self.token_received)

    def start_oauth(self):
        """Start the OAuth2 flow."""
        self.oauth.grant()

    def token_received(self):
        pass

    def auth_status_changed(self, status):
        print(status)

    def access_granted(self):
        print(f"Token received: {self.oauth.token()}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = OAuthApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Behaviour which I observe:

- application starts
- when I press the button it connects to the browser
- I see Google Auth window and can provide my credentials
- when I press connect, the app fails with an error above

```
qt.networkauth.replyhandler: Error transferring
   https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token - server replied:

qt.networkauth.oauth2: Unexpected call
```

How can I fix or at least debug the application?